# Why doesn't ANTLR "over-reduce" this expression?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lr-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
expr : factor op ;
op
    : '+' factor op
    | // Blank rule for left-recursion elimination
    ;

factor 
    : NUM
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

NUM : ('0'..'9')+ ;
```

I supply `2 + 3`, using `expr` as the start rule. The resulting parse tree from ANTLR is correct; however, I think I am misunderstanding the shift-reduce methods it uses.

I would expect the following to happen:

```
 Step # | Parse Stack   | Lookahead | Unscanned | Action
 1      |               | NUM       | + 3       | Shift
 2      | NUM           | +         | 3         | Reduce by factor -> NUM
 3      | factor        | +         | 3         | Shift a 'null'?
 4      | factor null   | +         | 3         | Reduce by op -> null
 5      | factor op     | +         | 3         | Reduce by expr -> factor op
 6      | expr          | +         | 3         | Shift
 7      | expr +        | NUM       |           | Shift
 8      | expr + NUM    |           |           | Reduce by factor -> NUM
 9      | expr + factor |           |           | ERROR (no production)
```

I would've expected an error to occur at step 3 wherin the parser would `shift` a `null` onto the stack as a prerequisite to `reduce`ing the factor  "up" to an `expr`.

Does ANTLR only shift a `null` when it's strictly "required" because the resulting `reduce` will satisfy the grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that ANTLR doesn't use a shift-reduce parser; the generated parsers are recursive descent using an arbitrary amount of lookahead.

The steps of the parser would be something like:

```
Rule          | Consummed | Input
--------------+-----------+------
expr          |           | 2 + 3
..factor      |           | 2 + 3
....NUM       | 2         | + 3
..op          | 2         | + 3
....'+'       | 2 +       | 3
....factor    | 2 +       | 3
......NUM     | 2 + 3     |
....op        | 2 + 3     |
......(empty) | 2 + 3     |
```

From what I read about ANTLR, you could achieve the same result with the following changes to the original grammar:

```
expr: factor op*;
op: '+' factor;
...
```

Comment: Isn't recursive descent a top-down parsing method? I thought ANT**LR** produces bottom-up LR parsers?

Comment: (my confusion is that, when I read articles about **LR** I'm directed to bottom-up methods like shift-reduce wheras when I read about recursive descent I'm directed to top-down parsing methods)

Comment: Ok, I'm a complete idiot that needs to read the ANTLR reference. It produces an LL parser!

Comment: If it were bottom-up there would be no need to left-factor or remove left recursion.

Comment: For the records, 'LR' is 'language recognition', not the usual 'Left to right, Rightmost derivation' The whole name stands for 'Another Tool For Language Recognition' :o)

Comment: In addition to Read the F*****g Manual (RTFM) SO could do with Read The F*****g Acronym (RTFA) ;)